# log4j2 DailyRollingFileAppende separate log files on roll based pid in actual log

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

I've implemented a plugin that adds to log information about pid.

```
appender.DRFA.layout.pattern = %d{ISO8601} %5p **[%pid]** [%t] %c{2}: %m%n
```

Also there is another plugin for FilePattern conversion that adds pid to file when rolling takes place

```
appender.DRFA.filePattern = ${sys:some.log.dir}/${sys:some.log.file}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%pid
```

Trying to understand how to make next:

at the end of the day take all rows in log files that have specific pid and roll them to file with the same pid defined by pattern

```
appender.DRFA.filePattern = ${sys:some.log.dir}/${sys:some.log.file}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%pid
```

Comment: Is it `log4j` or `log4j2`? Also, what do you want to achieve?

Comment: it;s about log4j2. I want to have separate log files based based on pid. I've got different processes running that are writing to the same log file. At the end  of the day I want this file to be separated to several files with different names (e.g. some.log.2017-08-28.4231@localhost) that will contain only logs that are related to this process.

Comment: FYI, Multiple processes writing to same log file is not good way. Logs may get lost or overwritten. It would be better if you create separate log for each process or use some log daemon like rsyslog

Comment: yeah I know but this is what I've got to work with right now.

Comment: Instead of doing what you want through log4j2, it would be better if you create some separate application that parse all log files at the end of the day and separate all rows based on pid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log4j2 rollover cannot combine multiple log files into a single zip file. Rollover can rename and/or compress a single log file. What you *can* do is move all log files with the same `pid` info the same directory:

```
appender.DRFA.filePattern = ${sys:some.log.dir}.%pid/${sys:some.log.file}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}
```

If you need to compress multiple files together, or append these files together into a single text file, the built-in rollover cannot currently do that.

Take a look at the [custom delete action](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#CustomDeleteOnRollover) that can be triggered on rollover. 
You may be able to extend that into what you have in mind. Please raise a JIRA ticket if you need Log4j2 to make API changes for your custom rollover actions.

Comment: Another question. Is it possible to name actual target log file based on pid and write there logs related to this pid? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes that should be possible. Log4j 2.9 supports the `%pid` pattern converter as a built-in: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#PatternLayout